# change background of textarea with react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to change the background of the text in the textarea, how do I do it?

this way now

[image]

I want it like this

[image]

```
<textarea
        id="textarea1"
        name="textarea1"
        ref={(el) => {
          refContainer.current = el;
        }}
        spellCheck="false"
        style={{
          ...color,
          padding: 16,
          resize: "none",
          textAlign: textCenter && "center",
          fontFamily: "Roboto",
          outline: "none",
          fontSize: `${fontSize}px`,
          overflowY: scrollHidden && "hidden",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          width: mobile ? "calc(100% - 32px)" : "100%",
          height: "100%",
          lineHeight: "1.5",
        }}
      ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a container with background image. Suppose it has a class of .container. Then put your textarea tag into it:

```
.container {
   background-image: url("YOUR_BMW_IMAGE_HERE")

}

.container > textarea {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

**EDIT**///First you asked about background color of the textarea. Which is an HTML element, not the text itself. And you **GOT** your answer, My new modified answer to your **new and edited** question

Use your image as a background, then apply these styles:

```
.container {
   background-image: url("YOUR_BMW_IMAGE_HERE")
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   background-clip: text;

}

.container > textarea {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}

textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I just want to have the background of the text this code didn't work